# Go factory method polymorphism with pointers

Tags: go, polymorphism

```
type Foo interface {
    FooMethod()
}
type BarFoo struct {
}
func (f *BarFoo) FooMethod() {
}
func NewBarFoo() *Foo {
    return &BarFoo{}
}
```

**Error**:
Cannot use '&BarFoo{}' (type *BarFoo) as type *Foo

Why I get compilation error for such code? Does polymorphism work for pointers?

BTW, this code is fine

```
func NewBarFoo() Foo {
    return &BarFoo{}
}
```

Comment: When I want to return a pointer to interface, I mean that this must be a pointer because I will return a struct that implemented this interface, and I don't want to copy this struct, I want to return already built object.

Comment: In Go you almost never need to use pointers to interfaces, certainly not from a constructor function that doesn't need to retain the pointer for later use. Just change your code to the second version, the one returning `Foo`, that's the right way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to change the function signature to

```
func NewBarFoo() Foo {
    return &BarFoo{}
}
```

You are still returning a pointer, it just so happens that the pointer implements the interface

Comment: Yeah, I see, it's just a bit weird in terms of language syntax, my code looks valid, but compiler just argue ...